# What is relation between tsne and word2vec?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

As I know of, `tsne` is reducing dimension of word vector.

`Word2vec` is generate word embedding model with huge amount of data.

What is the relation between two?

Does `Word2vec` use `tsne` inside?

(I use `Word2vec` from `Gensim`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally they both use *gradient-descent* to reach their final optimized states. And both can be considered dimensionality-reduction operations. But, word2vec does not internally use t-SNE (or vice-versa).

**t-SNE** ("t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding") typically reduces many-dimensional data to 2- or 3-dimensions, for the purposes of plotting a visualization. It involves learning a mapping from the original dimensionality, to the fewer dimensions, which still keeps similar points near each other.

**word2vec** takes many text examples and learns a shallow neural-network that's good at predicting words from nearby words. A particular layer of that neural-network's weights, which represent individual words, then becomes the learned N-dimensional word-vectors, with the value of N often 100 to 600.

(There's an alternative way to create word-vectors called *GLoVE* that works a little more like t-SNE, in that it trains directly from the high-dimensional co-occurrence matrix of words, rather than from the many in-context co-occurrence examples. But it's still not t-SNE itself.)

You could potentially run t-SNE with a target dimensionality of 100-400. But since that end-result wouldn't yet yield nice plots, the maintenance of 'nearness' that's central to t-SNE won't have delivered its usual intended benefit.

You could potentially learn word2vec (or GLoVE) vectors of just 2- or 3-dimensions, but most of the useful similarities/arrangements that people seek from word-vectors would be lost in the crowding. And in a plot, you'd probably not see as strong visual 'clumping' of related-word categories, because t-SNE's specific high-to-low dimensionality nearness-preservation goal wasn't applied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question :  Is it possible after learning using `Word2vec` (size=300, which means dimension is 300) and reducing its whole trained word vector's dimension by `t-SNE` so that I could visualizing `Word2vec`'s result??

Comment: Yes, that'd be typical - use word2vec to make 300d vectors that have all their usual/desired positive qualities... but then use t-SNE down to 2d to (try to) visually illustrate some of the clusters/nearness-relationships that existed in the 300d data.

Comment: But Is there way to get whole trained vectors from `Word2Vec` model? I have looked for this in `Gensim` tutorial site(https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) But I don't think there is no api for getting whole vectors after training? T_T

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "whole trained vectors". There's a list of every known word in `model.wv.index2word`. You can get every vector with `model.wv[word]`. The vectors are all in numpy array `model.wv.syn0`, in the same order as `index2word`. To really understand what's possible, and since this is Python/open-source where the entire model is accessible & mutable, the best reference is the source code itself: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py